# Error: express-paginate: `limit` is not a number >= 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pagination

i'm using
**express-paginate** and **mongoose-paginate**

file structure is **express-generator**

i have latest version of all plugins

example taken from: 
https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate#example

**this error occurs everytime at**

```
pages: paginate.getArrayPages(req)(3, pageCount, req.query.page)
```

**my code is like**

```
pages: res.locals.paginate.getArrayPages(req)(3, categories.pages, 1)
```

When I comment this line
page renders succesfully but I cannot create links afterwards

**routes/category.js**

```
function getAllRecords(req , res , next){
    console.log("getAllRecords");
    var Category = res.categoryModel ; // models/categoryModel.js
     Category.paginate({}, { page: req.query.page, limit: req.query.limit }, function(err, categories) {
 if (err) throw err;
res.format({
            html: function() {
                res.render('category/admin', {
                models: categories.docs,
                'res':res,
                pageCount: categories.pages,
                itemCount: categories.total,
                pages: res.locals.paginate.getArrayPages(req)(3, categories.pages, 1)
                });
            },
            json: function() {
                // inspired by Stripe's API response for list objects
                res.json({
                object: 'list',
                has_more: res.locals.paginate.hasNextPages(req)(categories.pages),
                data: categories.docs
                });
            }
        });

    });


}
```

**app.js**

```
ar app = express();
// keep this before all routes that will use pagination
app.use(paginate.middleware(10, 50));
/***** Models ********/
var categoryModel = require('./models/categoryModel');
var modelsInsideCategoryController = {'categoryModel':categoryModel};
var category = require('./routes/category')(modelsInsideCategoryController);
app.use('/category', category);
```

**models/categoryModel.js**

```
// grab the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
// create a schema
var categorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {type:String,required:true},
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});
categorySchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
var Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = Category;
```

Comment: [Looking at the code](https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate/blob/a34a719fcc308bd8d82b46a9d51dc3bf05faae09/index.js#L61-L62), that error should only happen when you call `getArrayPages(req)()` with a first argument that isn't a number, or if it's below 0. Is the `3` in your example code hardcoded?

Comment: Yes , 3  is  hardcodded.

Comment: When I use console.log() limit , pageCout and currentPage in express-paginate/index.php
it gives

limit = [object Object] pageCount= undefined currentPage=undefined

Comment: Ah, I see what's going on. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: When I use console.log(limit) in express-paginate/index.php
it gives same json as console.log(req)
I cannot understand why?

Comment: @danish, May I ask for your package.json file for the example code, please? It might help me and others visiting this thread later to understand the deps to run this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [`paginate.getArrayPages()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate#paginategetarraypagesreq) requires `req` as argument and returns a function, when you use `res.locals.paginate.getArrayPages()`, `req` has already been passed ([here](https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate/blob/a34a719fcc308bd8d82b46a9d51dc3bf05faae09/index.js#L117)) and you shouldn't pass it yourself.

Try this:

```
pages : res.locals.paginate.getArrayPages(3, categories.pages, 1)
```

And the same applies for [`hasNextPages()`](https://github.com/expressjs/express-paginate/blob/a34a719fcc308bd8d82b46a9d51dc3bf05faae09/index.js#L116) as well:

```
 has_more : res.locals.paginate.hasNextPages(categories.pages)
```